# Unique sublists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list `D` containing many sublists. I want to identify unique sublists and remove the repeating ones. By unique, I mean all the elements are the same irrespective of the locations of specific elements. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
D=[[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5], [4, 1, 3, 6]]

for i in range(0,len(D)): 
    E=D[i].unique
    print(E)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    E=D[i].unique

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Why did you think that `D[i].unique` would work? What research have you done on this?

Comment: Where's the *unique* method define?

Comment: Try using `set`, `sorted`, or `collections.Counter`. Look up each one or try out a few cases with different orderings and duplicates to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined what you mean by "unique" precisely enough. If there are no repeats in the sublists, then you can do something like:

```
def unique_sublists(data):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for sub in data:
        uniq = frozenset(sub)
        if uniq not in seen:
            result.append(sub)
            seen.add(uniq)
    return result
```

If there *can* be repeats, you might need something like:

```
def unique_sublists(data):
    from collections import Counter
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for sub in data:
        uniq = frozenset(Counter(sub).items())
        if uniq not in seen:
            result.append(sub)
            seen.add(uniq)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set` to get unique items. If you don't care if order is changed, you can use list comprehension that sorts each sublist, converts it to a tuple so that it can be hashed, and then finally convert it to a set to remove duplicates.

```py
unique = set(tuple(sorted(a)) for a in D)
# convert back to lists
unique = [list(a) for a in unique]
```

If you do care about order, you can do a similar thing except make a dictionary to get the original sublist.

```py
unique = dict(zip([tuple(sorted(a)) for a in D], D)).values()
# convert back to lists
unique = [list(a) for a in unique]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, I will add the two I came up with:

1. Using map to order the lists and then set to remove the duplicated ones.

`list(set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), D)))`

2. Here using a temporary list to add only if the items have not been added yet.

   ```
   out = []
   for i in map(sorted, D):
       if i not in out: out.append(i)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method named 'unique' for Python lists hence the error.
To identify unique sublists, you can convert the sublists to tuples, create a set of tuples to remove duplicates, and then convert the tuples back to lists. You could solve this as below:

```
D = [[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5], [4, 1, 3, 6]]
#sort the sublist elements (I found this to be able to eliminate them by a set method below) that's if element order doesn't matter in your case
unique_tuples = set(tuple(sorted(sublist)) for sublist in D)

unique_sublists = [list(t) for t in unique_tuples]
print(unique_sublists)
[[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This is working.

```
D = [[0, 2, 3, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 0, 3, 5], [4, 1, 3, 6]]

unique_sublists = []
for sublist in D:
    if set(sublist) not in [set(x) for x in unique_sublists]:
        unique_sublists.append(sublist)

print(unique_sublists)
```

Comment: this is horribly inefficient. Use a `set` for `unique_sublists` and add `frozenset`s to it.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you mean?

Comment: To rephrase, make `unique_sublists` a `set()`, and instead of appending a sublist, append a `frozenset()` of the `sublist`. This way you don't have to do the list comprehension every loop